# Form submited with php stores 0s

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to submit a form entry done by the user but when the numbers are entered, 0 is entered into the database instead of the user entered value. Help please

Here is my

---

```
<?php
//once the submit the button is submited it connects to the database
if(isset($_POST['submitGrades'])) {
include ("account.php") ;
( $dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password ) )
                or    die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );

mysql_select_db( $project ); 
// this part checks the value of "id" that it exist in another table first
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM newstudent WHERE id = '$id'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    // Go ahead and insert everything in table1
    $data = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
        'gradeone' => $_POST[gradeone], //this stores as 0 in the database
        'gradetwo' => $_POST[gradetwo], //this stores as 0 in the database
        'gradethree' => $_POST[gradethree], //this stores as 0 in the database
    );

    // Make sure all the data is safe for entry into the database
    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        $data[$key] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "'";
    }
    $fields = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
    $values = implode(', ', array_values($data));
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO grades ($fields) VALUES ($values)");
    echo 'Your grades were submited.';
} else {
    echo 'The Student does not exist. Please Enter the student first.';
}}?>
```

And this is the HTML code

```
<form id="grades" action="php/grades.php" method="post" OnSubmit="setTimeout('reset_form()', 200); return true" >
<label>STUDENT ID</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="PLEASE ENTER STUDENT ID" class="input" maxlength="9" name="id" id="id"></br>
    <label>SUBJECT</label>
    <select class="input" name="subject" id="subject">
        <option>Select One</option>
        <option>Math</option>
        <option>Chemistry</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Physics</option>
        <option>French</option>
        <option>Computer Science</option>
        <option>Network</option>
    </select></br>
        <label>GRADE 1</label>
        <input type = "text" placeholder="OUT OF 100" class="input" maxlength="3" name="gradeone" id="gradeone"></br>
        <label>GRADE 2</label>
        <input type = "text" placeholder="OUT OF 100" class="input" maxlength="3" name="gradetwo" id="gradetwo"></br>
        <label>GRADE 3</label>
        <input type = "text" placeholder="OUT OF 100" class="input" maxlength="3" name="gradethree" id="gradethree"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitGrades" id="submitGrades"/> </form>
```

As I said before i need help in figuring why when user enters values into gradeone, gradetwo, gradethree it stores into the mysql database as 0's...

Comment: check that datatype of column is set to int or varchar?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, $_POST['gradeone']);`

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and therefore give unexpected behaviors. Use `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: you are missing quotes in $_POST[gradeone], $_POST[gradetwo],$_POST[gradethree]

Comment: missing quotes in _POST [xx] doesnt actually do anything different.

Comment: datatype of the column is set to int with max of 3

Comment: this `setTimeout('reset_form()', 200)` ?

Comment: @TimValishin Are you getting any value for `$_POST['subject']`?

Comment: just try adding quotes if it works

Comment: try giving values in select tag..

Comment: $values is simply a string of concatenated values every value needs to be quoted

Comment: @aaron yes "subject" is a varchar and a dropdown select menu, that stores no problem

Comment: Changes it like this `$values = implode("', '", array_values($data));
        $values = "'".$values."'";`

Comment: @plainjane ok ill try

Comment: As said by @Kits add values to options of select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the quotes change it like this

```
 $data = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
    'gradeone' => $_POST['gradeone'], //changed added quotes
    'gradetwo' => $_POST['gradetwo'], //changed added quotes
    'gradethree' => $_POST['gradethree'], //changed added quotes
 );
```

Changes this line

```
    $values = implode(', ', array_values($data));
```

Like

```
    $values = implode("', '", array_values($data));
    $values = "'".$values."'";
```

$_POST is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: whats does `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);` give you..include that output in your question

Answer (score 1):

```
'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
    'gradeone' => $_POST['gradeone'], 
    'gradetwo' => $_POST['gradetwo'], 
    'gradethree' => $_POST['gradethree']
);
```

try like this you are not adding a quotes

Comment: <option>Math</option> place of this all option tags put  <option value =" ">Math</option> put your value in "math ".

Comment: subject part works.. its the grade numerical input that doesnt sends to database

Answer (score 0):

Well, whats confusing me is this part

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM newstudent WHERE id = '$id'");
```

If you are selecting only `id`, how are you getting the values for `$_POST['gradeone'], $_POST['gradetwo'],$_POST['gradethree'] , $_POST['subject']`. You don't have any other query where all these columns are selected.

Comment: The whole idea is to enter the grade for existing student. If the student doesn't exist, the grades will not be entered. So that statement is just to check that the id exist in another table